# Change Backgroundworker Progress from other function

Tags: c#

I need to change my backgroundworker progress outside the DoWork Event is this possible ?

My code

```
private void progress_changed(string fileName, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
    Filename = fileName;
    // change the progress here
}

private void worker_DoWork(string fileName)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (obj, e) => progress_changed(fileName, e);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(progress_complete);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Link), Savepath);
}

private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    mainForm.dlist.Items[mainForm.dlist.Items.IndexOfKey(Filename)].SubItems[2].Text = progress.ToString() + "%";
    mainForm.dlist.Items[mainForm.dlist.Items.IndexOfKey(Filename)].SubItems[3].Text = "Downloading";
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? Is there work being performed in two different places, so that the background worker will eventually do **less** work?

Comment: As you can see on my code, i launch the event worker_Dowork, and inside it i instance a webclient, this webclient report progress to progress_changed, but if i change my ListView items in Main Form i get crossthread exception, so the webclient event only reports his only progress and then the backgroundworker progress event changes the listview item. but to raise the backgroundworker progress event i need to change the backgroundworker progress inside the webcliente progress event.

Comment: If your Bgw really only starts an Async then eliminate it. Right now your Completed event will fire before the download is complete.

Comment: And you're capturing the fileName var (field), that looks tricky too.

Comment: i'm just using the backgroundworker because without it the webcliente progress event keeps blinking my listview when update it.

Comment: I am doing a similar thing in my program, except my doWork method is calling an extremely long running synchronous process. I moved my Report Progress call to an event that is invoked when the variables associated with the long running event are updated. It works once, then the next time I run the background worker I getan exception on ReportProgress (This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal) I'm not sure Report progress can be outside of DoWork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the BackgroundWorker to the other function.  From there, you can call `ReportProgress`.  Alternatively, depending on your structure, you could make the BackgroundWorker a class field and access it that way.

Comment: already tried that, i get: This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal.

Comment: Oh, that is because you are doing an async operation.  Why are using a BackgroundWorker to perfrom an async operation?  That seems totally redundant.

Comment: i'm just using the backgroundworker because without it the webcliente progress event keeps blinking my listview when update it.